# Fragment in Activity crashing when trying to update TextView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a activity that has a TabLayout of Fragments. When the Activity is created, it does a network call and receives a POJO, which I use to set an image and the toolbar heading. Once this is done, I send the Object to one of the fragments in the TabLayout, so I can manipulate the data in the Tabs. The issue I am having is that when the fragment gets the object, it crashes with a Nullpointer for some reason.

I think its because the TextView is created, then the network call completes, and then I am trying to set the text on the TextView using the data in the POJO.

Fragment:

```
public class OverviewListItemFragment extends Fragment implements OverviewView {

  TextView overViewHeading;

  public OverviewListItemFragment() {
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,   Bundle savedInstanceState) {
overViewHeading = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.frag_overview_heading_textview);
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.overview_list_item_fragment, container, false);

}

@Override
public void populateOverviewViews(TradeItem aTradeItem) {
String title;
title = aTradeItem.getItem().getTradeTitle();

overViewHeading.setText(title);
System.out.println("Overview Trade Object title is: " + title);
}

/**
 * Called when a fragment is first attached to its context.
 * {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} will be called after this.
 *
 * @param context
 */
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
super.onAttach(context);
}
}
```

Activity:

```
public class ItemBuyNowActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ItemView {

  private ImageLoader mImageLoader = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getImageLoader();

  @Bind(R.id.coordinatorLayout_list_item)
  CoordinatorLayout mCoordinatorLayout;

  @Bind(R.id.collapsing_toolbar_buy_now_list_item)
  CollapsingToolbarLayout buyNowCollapsingToolbar;
  @Bind(R.id.buy_now_tool_bar)
  Toolbar toolbar;
  @Bind(R.id.buy_now_tabs)
  TabLayout buy_now_tabs;
  ViewPager buy_now_viewpager;

  private ItemPresenter presenter;
  private OverviewPresenter mOverviewPresenter;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_item_buy_now);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    buy_now_viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.buy_now_viewpager);
    setupViewPager(buy_now_viewpager);
    buy_now_tabs.setupWithViewPager(buy_now_viewpager);
    handleIntent(getIntent());

  }

  private void setupViewPager(ViewPager aBuy_now_viewpager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new OverviewListItemFragment(), "Overview");
    adapter.addFragment(new ShippingListItemFragment(), "Shipping");
    adapter.addFragment(new DescriptionListItemFragment(), "Description");
    adapter.addFragment(new PaymentListItemFragment(), "Payment");
    aBuy_now_viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);

  }

  private void handleIntent(Intent aIntent) {
    if (aIntent != null) {

      String tradeType = aIntent.getStringExtra("itemType");
      String tradeId = aIntent.getStringExtra("itemId");
      tradeId = "215409903";

      presenter = new ItemPresenterImpl(this, ItemBuyNowActivity.this);
      presenter.doListingServiceCall(tradeId);


    } else {
      System.out.println("Intent is null in " + ItemBuyNowActivity.class.getSimpleName());
    }

  }

  @Override
  public void populateListViews(TradeItem aTradeItem) {
    populateOverview(aTradeItem);
  }

  private void populateOverview(TradeItem aTradeItem){
    mOverviewPresenter = new OverviewPresenterImpl(new OverviewListItemFragment(), aTradeItem);
  }
  @Override
  public void loadBackgroundImage(Drawable aDrawable) {
    buyNowCollapsingToolbar.setBackground(aDrawable);

  }

  @Override
  public void displayErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {

  }



  class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
      super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
      return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
      return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
      mFragmentList.add(fragment);
      mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
      return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
  }


}
```

Logcat:

```
02-03 20:10:23.175 29085-29085/com.example.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                  at com.example.app.ui.fragments.OverviewListItemFragment.populateOverviewViews(OverviewListItemFragment.java:41)
                                                                  at com.example.app.listing.overview.OverviewPresenterImpl.<init>(OverviewPresenterImpl.java:14)
                                                                  at com.example.app.ui.activities.ItemBuyNowActivity.populateOverview(ItemBuyNowActivity.java:104)
                                                                  at com.example.app.ui.activities.ItemBuyNowActivity.populateListViews(ItemBuyNowActivity.java:100)
                                                                  at com.example.app.listing.ItemPresenterImpl.onResponse(ItemPresenterImpl.java:62)
                                                                  at com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest.deliverResponse(JsonRequest.java:65)
                                                                  at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
                                                                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can sort this issue out so it doesnt crash?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your logcat and some code snippet so that we can understand better

Comment: changes made as requested

Comment: Is your `frag_overview_heading_textview` in your `overview_list_item_fragment` layout xml?

Answer (score 0):

your issue happens in `OverviewListItemFragment.populateOverviewViews` which makes me believe that either the argument is null or the view hasn't been created.
are you calling `populateOverview` before `onViewCreated`?

Comment: no populateOverview is only called once the network call in the activity is completed, and then it passes the POJO to the fragment which then is supposed to set the content. This is very reliant on when the network call is complete

Comment: presenter.doListingServiceCall(tradeId); in the Activity, it gets passed to an interface which then PresenterImpl does the network call which then hands the resulting object back to the activity via Inteface.

This is received in the method:
 @Override 
  public void populateListViews(TradeItem aTradeItem) {
    populateOverview(aTradeItem);
  } 
the method populateOverview passes the same object to the Fragment but this is where the app crashes